# Como construir un proyecto java con jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Quiero construir mi proyecto desde un repositorio en jenkis con maven pero al momento de hacer el build me tira errores de compilacion diciendome que hacen falta clases pero cuando ejecuto mi proyecto en NetBeans genera el build sin problemas
¿Debo realizar una configuracion antes?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debes de verificar tu configuracion de maven global para tu proyecto, si requiere algun repositorio externo que resuelva dependencias que no sean los que se usan por defecto en maven.
Quizás tambien tengas que comprobar si el agente jenkins tiene acceso al repositorio de maven (si está en internet, tiene acceso a internet bien directamente o usando un proxy)

Además se entiende que el paquete com.google.gson deberia de tener la dependencia bien puesta en el fichero pom.xml

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```